# Home Wireless Configuration

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

Just as shown on the image attached, I have two access points (Red and Green), both are connected using a LAN cable, both are configured to use the same SSID and password. both have devices connected using LAN cables too. there's a good distance between the APs. The cable between the devices can't be removed as I use my TV to stream stuff from my desktop.

[image]

My problem is that when my devices (phone, tablet, laptop) are connected to AP Red and get close to AP Green, the devices switches to the AP Green automatically and it causes all connections that I have on the devices (download, phone calls, streaming...etc) to drop. Same thing happens the other way around too.

How do I get to configure the access points to avoid drops while maintaining access to wireless anywhere at home? Perhaps my question should be about the best wireless mode that I'm supposed to use, I'm not sure if Repeater or Bridge will help, since that will force me to remove the LAN cables between the access points?

Help?

Comment: You need something called "seamless roaming (zero handoff)". This is supported e.g. on some Ubiquity APs. I don't know if your APs support it, and even if they do, it may be difficult to get it to work on routers of different brands, as the APs must cooperate for this.